# Scaling to be a specific height in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game like Pong, except you control both paddles and try to keep the ball in bounds. I want the paddle to always be 1/3 of the height of the screen for all resolutions. So if the Height = 900, then the paddle should be 300 high. For some reason, I can't seem to find a way that works for all resolutions anywhere. I feel I need to accomplish this through a script. Here is an image of the components for my paddle.

[image]

I need a generic formula so the paddle height is always 1/3 of the screen height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the canvas height and assign the paddle sizeDelta to have y size equal to the canvas height divided by 3.

This is the script, assumed you attach it to the paddle:

```
public Canvas myCanvas;

void Start() {
    float canvasHeight = myCanvas.pixelRect.height;
    GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.x, canvasHeight/3f);
}
```

Comment: Are you saying I should put it in a canvas then change the size of the RectTransformer?

Comment: I've seen you have a RectTransform component attached to the paddle so I assumed you have it inside a canvas. If it is so, yes, you change the width of the RectTransform component of the paddle.
If you're not using a canvas then you could use a script to get the camera size (assuming the camera covers all the screen).

Comment: Is this for Images or Sprites in a SpriteRenderer

Comment: It modifies the width of the RectTransform, this means it will work as long as a RectTransform component is attached.

Comment: I forgot to mention that SpriteRenderers work only **outside** canvases, in this case you will have to use the Image component.

Comment: How then would the box collider scale?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113355/discussion-between-cress-and-luke).